# Can I request for BIVS visa while going for job interview in Ireland?

Tags: ireland, northern-ireland

Here - https://www.dfa.ie/media/embassyindia/ourservices/bivsinformationnoteforpubrev3.pdf, it states that

- Visit (family/friend)
- Visit (tourist)
- Conference/Event
- Business

category visas are eligible for BIVS scheme. Since I am going for an interview, my category will be other, as stated here - http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-short-work. If my interviews finish early, I wish to visit Belfast. So, can I request BIVS endorsed visa for my case?

Comment: For clarity, what type of visa did you apply for? It’s not normally possible to switch visa type during the application process

Comment: @Traveller I am applying for Short Stay (C) visa. I am not asking for a switch. BIVS is an endorsement on Short Stay visas.

Comment: BIVS is not something you can request. Your application will automatically be considered for it and you will automatically receive it if you are eligible.